# DialogFlow Custom Payload with Context

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to add in the custom payload wihin Dialogflow a text response along with an output context. How can this be done? [image: f]

Answer (score 0):

Custom payload does not contain output context.
If you want to add output context you need to add it in output contexts like in the image below :

[image]

Hope it helps.